# Setting state in React.js (TypeScript) is giving problem

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-router, setstate

I'm new with typescript, so I was creating a blog-app in which user can write blog(only text) with title and blog body. When, **Add** button is clicked blog should be added to blogs array and user should be redirected to **Blogs** page.

**Problem:** When **Add** button is clicked blog is added to array but user is not redirected.

Below is code:

**Add.tsx**

```
interface Props {
  setBlogs: (blog: IBlog) => void;
}

function Add(props: Props) {
  const [info, setInfo] = useState<IBlog>({ title: "", body: "" });
  const [clicked, setClicked] = useState<boolean>(false);

  function handleInfoChange(
    e:
      | React.ChangeEvent<HTMLTextAreaElement>
      | React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>
  ) {
    const name: string = e.target.name;
    const value: string = e.target.value;

    setInfo(
      (preInfo): IBlog => {
        return { ...preInfo, [name]: value };
      }
    );
  }

  function addClick() {
    if (info.body.length > 0 && info.title.length > 0) {
      props.setBlogs(info);
      setClicked(true);
    }
  }

  React.useEffect(() => {
    console.log("Clicked", clicked);
  }, [clicked]);

  return (
    <div className="add">
      <div className="compileArea">
        <input
          type="text"
          id="title"
          name="title"
          autoComplete="off"
          placeholder="Title"
          value={info.title}
          onChange={handleInfoChange}
        />
        <textarea
          name="body"
          id="body"
          cols={30}
          rows={10}
          placeholder="Type here"
          value={info.body}
          onChange={handleInfoChange}
        ></textarea>

        <div className="controls">
          <button id="add-button" onClick={addClick}>
            Add
          </button>
        </div>
      </div>
      {clicked ? <Redirect to="./blogs" /> : null}
    </div>
  );
}

export default Add;
```

**IBlog looks like this:**

```
type IBlog = {
  title: string;
  body: string;
};
```

**App.tsx**

```
function App() {
  const [blogs, setBlogs] = React.useState<IBlogs>([]);

  function setblogs(blog: IBlog): void {
    setBlogs([...blogs, blog]);
  }

  React.useEffect(() => {
    console.log("Blog", blogs);
  }, [blogs]);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Header />
      <Switch>
        <Route path="/" exact />
        <Route
          path="/add"
          exact
          component={() => <Add setBlogs={setblogs} />}
        />
        <Route path="/blogs" exact component={() => <Blogs blogs={blogs} />} />
      </Switch>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

The thing is if I remove `setBlogs([...blogs, blog]);` in function `setblogs` in file `App.tsx`. User is redirected to **Blogs** page successfully.

If someone want to reproduce the error full project is [here](https://github.com/shivang51/blog-app.git).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the issue happens at Route declaration at app:

```
<Route
  path="/add"
  exact
  component={() => <Add setBlogs={setblogs} />}
/>
```

when you declare a function while passing to a prop, a new function will be created everytime `App` component updates. In this way, when you call `props.setBlogs(info)`, `App` updates and `component` receives a new function causing `Add` to rerender everytime.

to avoid that, one way you could pass a function like `component={renderAdd}`. createAdd is the same function, but alredy declared and wrapped in useCallback like:

```
const renderAdd = useCallback(
  () => <Add setBlogs={setblogs} />,
  [setBlogs],
)
```

other way, which I think is cleaner, is to pass your component as child to Route:

```
<Route
  path="/add"
  exact
>
  <Add setBlogs={setblogs} />
</Route>
```